# How to make a HTML5 scrolling page as in this example?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am interested in making HTML5 page with page scrolling like this one: http://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/

I would be grateful is someone could point out how this scrolling is made and/or what frameworks are involved or could reach identical result.

Comment: It's a Javascript library called script.aculo.us: http://script.aculo.us/

Comment: scriptaculous is dead. last release is from December 23, 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy.

Make bind to mouse scroll, and create slides.

```
<div class="b-slider">
   <div class="b-sider__item">
      Item 1
   </div>
   <div class="b-sider__item">
      Item 2
   </div>
   <div class="b-sider__item">
      Item 3
   </div>
   <div class="b-sider__item">
      Item 4
   </div>
   <div class="b-sider__item">
      Item 5
   </div>
</div>
```

And use jcarousel slider plugin with vertical scroll options

```
$('.b-slider').jcarousel('next');
```

Comment: To reach a similiar result he must work with the css `transition` value.