# Is it possible to find the function that caused page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I am trying to find which function is causing the page to scroll when hovering an element, but so far I got nothing.

There is no specific listener attached to the element, from what I could understand it is triggered via a `mouseover` listener or similar, the elements contain lots of listeners attached to them.

Also this is not a browser function, it is specific to javascript because it doesn't occur when I null the majority of the code.

I already tried to `null`ing the scroll methods I know of like so:

```
[
    'scroll',
    'scrollTo',
    'scrollBy',
    'scrollByLines',
    'scrollByPages',
    'scrollX',
    'scrollY',
    'scrollMaxX',
    'scrollMaxY',
    'scrollHeight',
    'scrollIntoView',
    'scrollTop',
    'scrollTopMax'
].forEach(function(a) {
    window[a] = null;
    document.documentElement[a] = null;
})
```

Hoping that when the mysterious function tried to call the scroll method it would throw an error, but instead it still scrolls normally without any problems.

I also tried listening to the scroll event, but no returned argument brings me closer to the responsible function.

I have tried looking for it in the minified source code, but the common `scroll` search returns 266 results and I am not even sure if it is using a typical scroll method.

Is there any way that I can locate the function that is making the page scroll?

Comment: Locate the source of mouseover event and check this function. Also try to function a handler using something like this: `getEventListeners(document.querySelector('.link'));`

Comment: @dfsq The mouseover handles a multitude of other functions, all of them minified and I already explained that the elements have lots of listeners attached to them.

Comment: @vsync It is the page that gets scrolled because I can clearly see the page moving and a scroll event occurs if I attached a listener to the window.

Comment: Even if there are hundred of listeners you can list them all with getEventListeners.

Comment: @dfsq What will I be able to do with so many listeners that lead to even more call stacks, most being distributed by `.call()` and `.apply()`? It will end up being the same thing as debugging the entire code line by line.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are not that many listeners, and it's possible to examine code if each of them. You can use more advanced tools if you want, check SpyJS.

Comment: @dfsq Sorry, but that is not a solution that I am looking for, I am trying to find a simpler way, not a more complicated one. There are multiple modules attached to the same listeners, each relays the events to hundreds of intricate and interconnected functions, all of them in minified code with the biggest modules containing more than 15,000 lines of code. Maybe if you know of different scroll methods that I didn't list in my question it will be more helpful than your suggestion.
Here is an example of one of the modules https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-en_US-vfl25nD3n/common.js

Comment: You could try this Visual Event bookmarklet: http://pastebin.com/LUpteqrt. Create a new bookmark, add the entire code as the url, click the bookmark while viewing your page. It'll create an overlay on each element for every event it has. You can remove events overlays one at a time to single out the event that you're looking for.

Comment: @StephanMuller That suggestion is completely useless because the issue here is not finding what event is attached to which element, finding that was never a problem. I'd appreciate if you pay more attention to the information I have provided.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After 3 days of trying to find this mysterious function it came to me after posting the same question a second time, the function that is causing the page to scroll ended up being the `.focus()` function. I remembered it from a long time ago, but since I never used it ever since I learned about it and it isn't easy to relate to all the other scroll functions, it was giving me a hard time.

Thank you all that tried to pitch in with this. Hopefully someone else in the future will find this useful.

Comment: Thank you! In my case, I was working with a legacy WebForms app, and the page was scrolled to the top due to a `DefaultFocus` attribute on a `form` element: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultfocus.aspx?PHPSESSID=tn8k5...

Answer (score 31):

In 2020, go to Chrome's Dev Tools, `Sources` tab, and on the right pane, scroll to the very bottom to find `Event Listener Breakpoints`.

There you'll find `scroll` inside the `Control` group. Clicking on the checkbox will stop execution (it's a breakpoint) whenever the scroll event is fired, and you'll be able to trace the code who did it in the same pane (right side), under the `Call Stack` group (it's probably the first group in the right pane after debugger kicks in).

[image]

Comment: This stops the execution on "scroll" event but the trace who triggered it is lost so it does not help. You see only the current stack trace of running javascript threads but if something set body.scrollTop=0 that javascript is gone and not visible in the list anymore.

Comment: As @elixon says, this does not help find the source of the scroll event.

Comment: It also doesn't work on element-level scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered a very similar unexpected scroll in our application recently and eventually narrowed down the culprit to Modernizr's CSS Hyphens feature detection.

Bug report here:
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/2172

As in your case, the scrolling was caused by a call to .focus(), so it eluded our initial searches for unwanted "scroll" code calls.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a Component with an input with the autoFocus property

```
<input type="text" autoFocus={true} />
```

I removed the property

```
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<div onmouseover="scrollWin()">Hover over me and it scrolls down the page</div>
<p>You will need stuff here to see the scroll work</p>
<script>
function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 100);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have to create the function, in this case it's scrollWin()

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Comment: This answer is absolutely unrelated to the question I asked. I want to discover (debug might be a better word) which function is being responsible for page scroll, not create a new one. Right at the start of my question I clearly said "I am trying to find which function is causing the page to scroll...", `find` - not `create` or `make`. Even the title itself is very clear.

Comment: How about this. You want to know which function is responsible for page scroll? On which page? It could be content appending if all I know, and maybe you're not really seeing a scroll. Your first sentence clearly says you're trying to find a function that creates page scroll. I gave you an example of one, and an example on how to use it.

Also, maybe try searching for other possibilities like jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442717/how-to-make-a-html5-scrolling-page-as-in-this-example

Comment: You are not reading things correctly, I clearly said "I AM TRYING TO FIND WHICH FUNCTION IS CAUSING THE PAGE TO PAGE SCROLL" not "TRYING TO CREATE A FUNCTION THAT CAUSES THE PAGE TO SCROLL". In no way in my entire question have I ever asked to create any function that scrolls a page, I am trying to find the one responsible for scrolling the page I am studying and I have already said that it is really a page scroll because it triggers the "scroll" event when I add a listener to that same event. Please stop suggesting me to create more scroll functions or even use libraries which are useless.